# Why lambdas passed as argument cannot redefine variable internally

Tags: java, lambda

Why the Java Compiler don't allow us to create a homonymous variable in the function's local scope when we are passing a lambda as an argument?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Consumer<String> func = s -> System.out.println(s);

        Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add("lion");
        s.add("tiger");
        s.add("bear");
        s.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s)); //it dont!
        //s.forEach(func); //it works!
    }
}
```

Error:

```
/MyClass.java:12: error: variable s is already defined in method main(String[])
        s.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
              ^
1 error
```

Comment: That would be a question for the designers of Java.  But it seems like a sensible design decision to me.  Nothing worse than having two different variables in scope, with the same name.

Comment: As a side note, `s.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));` can be reduced to `s.forEach(System.out::println);`, which uses a method reference.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, thanks.  I was wondering if there was some characteristic in the JVM's conceptual data model that make it impossible.

Comment: I'm sure that when lambdas were introduced, the designers could have designed them in a way that made this possible.  I think what they've done was the more sensible choice.

Comment: Note also that you can define the Consumer func before the HashSet definition, but not after using the same variable s. One would think that if they share the same scope, that would not be possible.  So it appears it's more than just a scoping issue.

Comment: @jim829 That's consistent with other scoping. If you declare a variable name in a block (e.g. `if`, `for`, `{}`, etc.), then you can use the same name after the block but not before. This makes sense; if the variable was before the block then there's a conflict, but after the block and the variable inside said block has fallen out of scope—no conflict.

Comment: The idea of a code block didn't occur to me because the variable 's' appears to be just sitting out there.  With if, for, etc, you have () or some other braces to visibly identify a block.  So it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 's' in scope at the point at which 'func' is declared, and therefore the formal parameter 's' of the lambda expression is not shadowing anything.

There is an 's' in scope at the point at which s.foreach is invoked with a lambda expression as actual parameter, and therefore the formal parameter 's' of the lambda expression is shadowing the existing 's', which is illegal.

The appropriate parts of the language specification are those describing [scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) and [shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4).  The issue is not specific to lambda expressions; it perhaps looks that way due to the happenstance placement of your declaration of 'func', which just happens to be before 's'.